# latex \textbackslash does not work, rmarkdown html

Tags: html, latex, r-markdown, backslash

I want to include the `\textbackslash` in a latex math formula in a rmarkdown html document. I am working with bookdown. here is a sample code:

```
---
title: "Probabilidad"
author: "Nicolás Molano Gonzalez"
date: "7 de Abril de 2020"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2: default
---
here is some useless text
now I want to do this $A \textbackslash B$ but it does not work properly
```

The `$A \textbackslash B$` is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\setminus`, `\smallsetminus` or `\backslash` instead.  The problem is that `bookdown::html_document2` is using MathJax, and by design it only handles math-mode macros.  See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511331) for a discussion of the differences.